# authentication in MongoDB and Ubuntu

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

We installed MongoDB on windows(development) version 3.4, and enabled authentication, after running the command `mongod --auth`, the authentication was successfully implemented. 
Now on the production server that is Ubuntu 16, with MongoDb version 4.0, we made changes to the mongod.conf file as seen below and then restated the mongod service with command `sudo service mongod start`, but now we are not able to connect to our MongoDB Ubuntu server.

```
security:
authorization: "enabled"
```

Where did we go wrong in implementing authentication for MongoDB on Ubuntu server.

Comment: Did you created an user?

Comment: yes db.createUser({ user: "Administrator", pwd: "********", roles: [{ role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" }] }).

Comment: Are you sure that `sudo service mongod start` is restarting server if this one is already running? try restart, or stop/start

Comment: yes we run each command one after the another first stop service and then start service.

Answer (score 0):

```
security:
authorization: "enabled"
```

2 possible issues here : reading the doc, i'm not sure you need to quote the enabled word.
Moreover, yaml format need to increment sub part of conf, so your conf file have to look like :

```
security:
  authorization: enabled
```

But cannot really test, since i don't have any running local instance

Comment: `security:
authorization: "enabled"` did not work.Pasting my config file for better understanding.`# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIpAll: true
  #bindIp: 127.0.0.1


# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

security:
authorization: "enabled"

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:

`

Comment: take care : enabled AND NOT "enabled"  ==>no quote

Comment: i have tried both both the combinations "enabled" and enabled, it does not work with both. Do i have to use the --auth option in the mongodb service start command ?